# Enviar email com Acentos BD Uft8

Tags: php, mysql, email

Estou com um problema ao enviar email com nomes que vem da base de dados.
Alguns nomes vem com acentos e quando recebo os emails os nomes estão desconfigurados.

A base de dados está como Utf8 - Default collation

Código php:

```
$PHPMailer->Charset = 'UTF-8';
$PHPMailer->Body = "<body>
<p>
<strong>
Faltam 10 dias para terminar um ou mais documentos do $Nome
</strong>
```

Já experimentei: (No inicio do codigo php)

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
```

Comment: Eu resolvi o meu problema pondo no cabeçalho do e-mail:
`Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n`

Comment: Você pode usar essas funções para lhe ajudar a detectar e converter para a codificação correta: `utf8_encode`, `mb_check_encoding`, `mb_detect_encoding`, `mb_convert_encoding`, `htmlentities`, `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: Na cabeçalho do email? E onde posso colocar essa função ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Para o envio do email correr sem problemas, deverás garantir que tudo está a utilizar o mesmo *charset*. Caso não, terás que proceder a conversões para que o email chegue em condições.

## Assumindo UTF-8

1. Os documentos de PHP deverão estar com a codificação em UTF-8.

   Como lidar com isto depende do IDE a ser utilizado, mas seja num IDE ou num editor de texto, existe sempre a opção de definir a codificação do ficheiro, bem como um local onde a mesma pode ser visualizada:

   [image: Captura de tela do Geany]
2. O documento que envia o email deverá conter a seguinte linha:

   ```
   <?php
   header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

   // o teu código
   ?>
   ```

   Colocar ao início do documento antes de qualquer *output* ou operação.
3. A base de dados, as tabelas e seus respectivos campos deverão estar com a *Collation* em UTF-8.

   Para garantir que não vai existir necessidade de conversão entre *charsets* os dados devem ser armazenados numa base de dados que contenha um charset igual ao utilizado para processar os mesmos.

   **Exemplo em MySQL**

   ```sql
   ALTER DATABASE minhaBaseDados CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
   ALTER TABLE minhaTabela CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
   ```
4. O charset do PHPMailer por defeito é o iso-8859-1 conforme pode ser visto na [documentação](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=properties) (Inglês). Para garantir um envio correcto com dados em UTF-8 é preciso definir o *charset*:

   ```
   $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
   ```

Com estes passos consegues garantir que em toda a tua aplicação os dados estão sempre com o *charset* UTF-8 evitando assim problemas com caracteres especiais, caracteres acentuados e/ou eventuais conversões entre *charsets*.

---

**Nota:**
Quando falamos em HTML e Ajax, as páginas devem conter os cabeçalhos também em UTF-8 para garantir uma apresentação correcta ao visitante e um envio correcto dos dados a partir do navegador para o servidor (Ajax):

```html
<!-- HTML 5 -->
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Parabéns, sua sugestão funcionou perfeitamente!!!

Comment: Usei a solução 4. Rodou certinho...Obrigado!