# Como força UTF-8 em PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Estou programando em *PHP*. Eu tenho uma `div` e dentro dela estou chamando outra tela por exemplo:

```
</div><!-- End col-md-6 -->
            <?php require_once ("partialView/carrinho_view.php"); ?>
```

Essa tela `carrinho_view.php` só tem outro `div` dentro com um carrinho, e não posso colocar nessa tela o meu `header.php`, porque ele já está sendo chamado na tela atual que estou chamando o `carrinho_view.php`... Com isso a tela `carrinho_view.php` não está aceitando o meta `utf-8`. Como faço para essa tela aceitar?

Comment: Olha se isso te ajuda ai https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22394/enviar-email-com-acentos-bd-uft8

Comment: Já utilizei (<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); ?> e não funciona, mas muito obrigado!

Comment: Caro Mayos, quando usa require include e afins tem que ter todos documentos salvos pelo editor de texto como UTF-8, fora que tem que ajustar a conexão de banco também, eu expliquei detalhadamente nesta resposta, leia com calma, ela ensina passo a passo como vc entender a codificação em documentos, banco e o envio do header, resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635 ... ela ficou grande pq cada pessoa usa um editor de texto e quase sempre alguem aparecia com uma duvida remotamente ligada e fui obrigado a evoluir a resposta, mas o geral que precisa estudar com ela é isso: [...]

Comment: [...]HTTP headers de resposta, conexão com o banco (charset do momento de conectar), estrutura do banco (codificação) e codificação de todos documentos .php, se ler com calma vai entender bem como funciona. Codecs e HTTP é algo que leva muito tempo para aprender, não se aprende nem em meses, então tenha paciencia e leia com paciencia que vai conseguir resolver rapido e aprender o básico do básico ;) ... ps: conheço programadores profissionais que até hoje não entendem bem codecs e estrutura HTTP, pq pulam o básico, então vá com calma e me avise de qualquer necessidade

Comment: Certo Guilherme Nascimento, muito obrigado amigo!

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente Guilherme Nascimento, me ajudou muito. Obrigado!

Comment: Por nada caro Mayos, tudo de bom!